# What are "normal" amounts of data to store in a database?

Tags: mysql, storage

For my project, a web application, I need to store user data in a database. Obviously all users are stored together with their unique ID, but what about "items" users create within the application?

After a user is logged in they can create "items" within the application, whatever an item may be. Each item has a bunch of properties created by the user. I could create a table named "user_items" with an item ID and the user ID of the user who created it. But what if the app has 1000 users that all created 50 items with at least 10 properties? That would create 50000 records with 10 columns. So I start to wonder...

Does this ever create loading issues (slow down the processes) on the average server?

What are normal amounts of data to store in a database?

Comment: There isn't any normal amount of data. Varies greatly application to application. I've seen tables millions of records. 50,000 is very small - especially with a server that has reasonable RAM, CPU, etc. (based on the traffic you receive/queries you have to make). Using database indexes you can speed things up too. If you didn't have enough system resources (RAM, CPU) you'd likely start to see issues or longer response times. As you add more and more data, there is more to search through so it would be slower as the amt of data increases. If you're just getting a website going, I wouldn't worry

Comment: Modern databases and computers (even your personal laptop or desktop) can easily handle millions of records...

Comment: Ahh, that is such a relief. Thank you for your quick responses!

Comment: A single-row, single-column table is "normal" in some situations.  A multi-billion row table is "normal in some situations.  50K rows is "small" today.  As for "processing" -- Let's see the `SELECTs`, `UPDATEs`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very high level:

- a modern RDBMS, running on modern hardware, can handle tables with hundreds of millions of rows, and still return results quickly.
- but only if it's well designed and can use indexes for your queries.
- some queries can't use indexes, for instance wildcard searches on character fields (e.g. `where name like '%bob%'`)
- the performance of your application will likely deteriorate with large numbers of **concurrent** users, and you need to make sure each page request doesn't generate hundreds of database requests. If you have 1000 users all using the site at exactly the same time, and each request needs 100 database queries to render your page, your database may not have enough resources to process those queries simultaneously.

Comment: There are specialised indexes for keyword searches, but they are that - specialised. You have to set them up specifically for that kind of query